# Comparing Two Times: jQuery and database

Tags: jquery

I want to compare two variable that contain time values, but one is produced when the page is created and another is retrieved from a database. Also, I want to create a timer that starts when the page is created and shows alert when we receive the database time.

What solution would you suggest for doing these two tasks in jQuery?

> 1) How can I obtain a database time value using jQuery?
>   2) How can I create a timer that starts when page is created?

Comment: I think this should be the work of server-script

Comment: if i do it when the number of user that using system increase the server will be down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make some assumptions

- your server-side scripting language is php
- your time value is a Unix simestamp (seconds since 1 January 1970)
- jQuery is installed on the page (your question is tagged jQuery).

First, serve your page with the database time value in a suitable HTML container:

```
<?php
//retrieve value from database here.
$dbTimeValue = ......;
?>

<body>
...
<input type="hidden" id="dbTimeValue" value="<?php echo $dbTimeValue ?>" />
...
</body>
```

Then, client-side, in javascript:

```
$(function() {
    var dbTimeVal = Number( $("#dbTimeValue").val() ) * 1000;//Unix timestamp converted to milliseconds
    var timeNow = (new Date()).getTime();//time now (from client computer's motherboard) expressed in milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970
    var timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Time now is later than database time");
    }, timeNow - dbTimeVal);
});
```

Note: The database time value could be served directly into javascript with `var dbTimeVal = <?php echo $dbTimeValue ?>;` but this is arguably more confusing to a noob.